# Scroll overflow under top and bottom divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a chat ui from this Codepen https://codepen.io/Momciloo/pen/bEdbxY . The content in left sidebar scrolls fine after I added an `overflow:auto` and set the height for he scrolling div. I cant seem to get scrolling to work on the right side chat section.I woould like to have the chat bubbles scroll under both the input field and the `.top` div. My first solution was to set a `height` and an `overflow-y:scroll` but the chat bubbles overflow the ui .I've added the snippet below. Any solutons?

```js
$('.chat[data-chat=person2]').addClass('active-chat');
$('.person[data-chat=person2]').addClass('active');

$('.left .person').mousedown(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('.active')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var findChat = $(this).attr('data-chat');
        var personName = $(this).find('.name').text();
        $('.right .top .name').html(personName);
        $('.chat').removeClass('active-chat');
        $('.left .person').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.chat[data-chat = '+findChat+']').addClass('active-chat');
    }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600);
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: url("http://s17.postimg.org/fr01hfe33/image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
          transform: translate(-50%, 0);
          overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container .left {
  float: left;
  width: 37.6%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container .left .top {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 96px;
  padding: 29px;
}
.container .left .top:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
          transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.container .left input {
  float: left;
  width: 188px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  border-radius: 21px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.container .left input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.container .left a.search {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #00b0ff;
  background-image: url("http://s11.postimg.org/dpuahewmn/name_type.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top 12px left 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.container .left .people {
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height:440px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container .left .people .person {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 10% 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container .left .people .person:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
          transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.container .left .people .person img {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.container .left .people .person .name {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.container .left .people .person .time {
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10%;
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container .left .people .person .preview {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  width: 70%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #999;
}
.container .left .people .person.active, .container .left .people .person:hover {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #00b0ff;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  padding-left: calc(10% + 1px);
}
.container .left .people .person.active span, .container .left .people .person:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
}
.container .left .people .person.active:after, .container .left .people .person:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
.container .right {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 62.4%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container .right .top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 47px;
  padding: 15px 29px;
  background-color: #eceff1;
}
.container .right .chat {
  height:437px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container .right .top span {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999;
}
.container .right .top span .name {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.container .right .chat {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 35px 92px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
  height: calc(100% - 48px);
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.04, 1, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, -0.04, 1, 1);
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.15s;
  animation-duration: 0.15s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.45s;
  animation-duration: 0.45s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.05s;
  animation-duration: 1.05s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.2s;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.35s;
  animation-duration: 1.35s;
}
.container .right .chat.active-chat .bubble:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
.container .right .write {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 29px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  width: calc(100% - 58px);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.container .right .write input {
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  width: 347px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.container .right .write .write-link.attach:before {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 42px;
  content: '';
  background-image: url("http://s1.postimg.org/s5gfy283f/attachemnt.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.container .right .write .write-link.smiley:before {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 42px;
  content: '';
  background-image: url("http://s14.postimg.org/q2ug83h7h/smiley.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.container .right .write .write-link.send:before {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 11px;
  content: '';
  background-image: url("http://s30.postimg.org/nz9dho0pp/send.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.container .right .bubble {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding: 13px 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.container .right .bubble:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 6px;
  content: '\00a0';
  -webkit-transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
          transform: rotate(29deg) skew(-35deg);
}
.container .right .bubble.you {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00b0ff;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
      -ms-flex-item-align: start;
          align-self: flex-start;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideFromLeft;
  animation-name: slideFromLeft;
}
.container .right .bubble.you:before {
  left: -3px;
  background-color: #00b0ff;
}
.container .right .bubble.me {
  float: right;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-item-align: end;
          align-self: flex-end;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideFromRight;
  animation-name: slideFromRight;
}
.container .right .bubble.me:before {
  right: -3px;
  background-color: #eceff1;
}
.container .right .conversation-start {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .right .conversation-start span {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #999;
}
.container .right .conversation-start span:before, .container .right .conversation-start span:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.container .right .conversation-start span:before {
  left: 0;
}
.container .right .conversation-start span:after {
  right: 0;
}

@keyframes slideFromLeft {
  0% {
    margin-left: -200px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideFromLeft {
  0% {
    margin-left: -200px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slideFromRight {
  0% {
    margin-right: -200px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideFromRight {
  0% {
    margin-right: -200px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="top">
                <input type="text" />
                <a href="javascript:;" class="search"></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="people">
                <li class="person" data-chat="person1">
                    <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/ih41k9tqr/img1.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="name">Thomas Bangalter</span>
                    <span class="time">2:09 PM</span>
                    <span class="preview">I was wondering...</span>
                </li>
                <li class="person" data-chat="person2">
                    <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/yf86x7z1r/img2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="name">Dog Woofson</span>
                    <span class="time">1:44 PM</span>
                    <span class="preview">I've forgotten how it felt before</span>
                </li>
                <li class="person" data-chat="person3">
                    <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/h9q4sm433/img3.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="name">Louis CK</span>
                    <span class="time">2:09 PM</span>
                    <span class="preview">But we’re probably gonna need a new carpet.</span>
                </li>
                <li class="person" data-chat="person4">
                    <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/quect8isv/img4.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="name">Bo Jackson</span>
                    <span class="time">2:09 PM</span>
                    <span class="preview">It’s not that bad...</span>
                </li>
                <li class="person" data-chat="person5">
                    <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/ete1l89z5/img5.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="name">Michael Jordan</span>
                    <span class="time">2:09 PM</span>
                    <span class="preview">Wasup for the third time like is 
you bling </span>
                </li>
                <li class="person" data-chat="person6">
                    <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/kwi7e42rh/img6.jpg" alt="" />
                    <span class="name">Drake</span>
                    <span class="time">2:09 PM</span>
                    <span class="preview">howdoyoudoaspace</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="top"><span>To: <span class="name">Dog Woofson</span></span></div>
            <div class="chat" data-chat="person1">
                <div class="conversation-start">
                    <span>Today, 6:48 AM</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    Hello,
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    it's me.
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    I was wondering...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat" data-chat="person2">
                <div class="conversation-start">
                    <span>Today, 5:38 PM</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    Hello, can you hear me?
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    I'm in California dreaming
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    ... about who we used to be.
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    Are you serious?
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    When we were younger and free...
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    I've forgotten how it felt before
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat" data-chat="person3">
                <div class="conversation-start">
                    <span>Today, 3:38 AM</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    Hey human!
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    mm... Someone took a t in the hallway.
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    ... what.
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    Are you serious?
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    I mean...
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    It’s not that bad...
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    But we’re probably gonna need a new carpet.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat" data-chat="person4">
                <div class="conversation-start">
                    <span>Yesterday, 4:20 PM</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    Hey human!
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    Umm... Someone took a shit in the hallway.
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    ... what.
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    Are you serious?
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    I mean...
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    It’s not that bad...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat" data-chat="person5">
                <div class="conversation-start">
                    <span>Today, 6:28 AM</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    Wasup
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    Wasup
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    Wasup for the third time like is <br />you 
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="chat" data-chat="person6">
                <div class="conversation-start">
                    <span>Monday, 1:27 PM</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    So, how's your new phone?
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    You finally have a smartphone :D
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    Drake?
                </div>
                <div class="bubble me">
                    Why aren't you answering?
                </div>
                <div class="bubble you">
                    howdoyoudoaspace
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="write">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="write-link attach"></a>
                <input type="text" />
                <a href="javascript:;" class="write-link smiley"></a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="write-link send"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the display flex from your .container .right .chat.active and add a wrapper-div containing all your bubbles. This wrapper will have a height and overflow-y: auto.

```
.conversation-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

check this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzqpoO
PS: I did the change only for the case of "Thomas Bangalter" in your example. You have to adjust the css properties to fit your goals.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you've set justify-content as flex-end.
If you set it as initial it would solve problem.

```
.container .right .chat {
    justify-content : flex-end;
}
```

But then placing bubbles at bottom comes next problem.
I think you can solve that by setting flex-direction as column-reverse.
And may be you have to put content in reverse order.

```
.container .right .chat {
    justify-content : initial;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```